# Powershell - Find and move files with specific extension while retaining folder structure

Tags: powershell

My file server has many scattered video files.

I am attempting to archive them to a separate server.
However I need to retain each individual file's file-path/folder structure in the new server.

Example:

`get-childitem "D:\*" -Filter *.mp4 -recurse`

This returns all the files with an .mp4 extension and their folder path.

But how can I copy exclusively said .mp4 files, ignore all other files, but copy their directory and parent directories?

If a file resides here for example:
Directory:

D:\Operating Systems & Software\Programs\Security+\AAA and Authentication - CompTIA Security+ SY0-501 - 4.1.mp4

I would like to recreate the folder structure in A: but only copy the .mp4 files. This means that the script recreates the folder structure, but ignores all files present inside said folders, except mp4 files, those files will be copied over to their respective sub-folder within the folder structure.

Answer (score 0):

You could accomplish this using something like this:

```
get-childitem "D:\*" -Filter *.mp4 -recurse | foreach-object {

    $source = $_.FullName
    $target = $Source.Replace("D:\", "A:\")

    Copy-Item -LiteralPath $source -Destination $target -Force
}
```

This script will not create the folder structure for folders that will become empty if there are no mp4 files in the source, but it will place the mp4 files in the correct location in the destination and create the folders if it needs to.

You can also use `move-item` to move them away from the source location. Just replace `copy-item` with `move-item`. I assumed copy because that's what your question asks for.

Comment: thanks a bunch, gave it a shot but I'm being met with the following error:
```Copy-Item : Could not find a part of the path 'A:\Videos I 
Filmed\20110714_192403(3).mp4'.
At line:6 char:5
+     Copy-Item -LiteralPath $source -Destination $target -Force
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Copy-Item], DirectoryNotFoundExcepti 
   on
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException,Microsoft.PowerShe 
   ll.Commands.CopyItemCommand```

Ill see about creating the structure first, then the copy

Answer (score 0):

This should create the necessary folders if they don't exist:

```
get-childitem "D:\*" -Filter *.mp4 -recurse | ForEach{
    $TargetPath = $_.DirectoryName -replace ('^C','A')
    If (!(Test-Path $TargetPath)) {
        mkdir $TargetPath | out-null
    }
    $_ | Copy-Item -Destination $TargetPath
}
```